# How to set attribute=' data-fancybox-group' in slip hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a gallery with directional hover. Earlier fancy box was not working while clicking on  image.. That worked fine when i used the following code  and added fancybox to the class.

Now to make arrows working how do i add  attribute data-fancybox-group='gallery'

```
$targetAParent = $element.parent('a');
            if ($targetAParent.length && instance.settings.withLink) {
                var url = $targetAParent.attr('href');
                $overlay = $('<a>', {
                    class: 'sliphover-overlay fancybox',
                    href: url || '#',
                    //.attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery"),
                }).css({
                    textDecoration: 'none'
                });
            }
```

Comment: In this case, you SHOULD provide a jsfiddle, otherwise it will be really really hard to help. Many people will reject from it.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your `$overlay` should get the attribute. If so write inside your if-statement:

```
$overlay = $('<a>', {
    class: 'sliphover-overlay fancybox',
    href: url || '#',
    'data-fancybox-group': "gallery"
 }).css({
     textDecoration: 'none'
 });
```

Another way would be:

```
$overlay = $('<a>', {
    class: 'sliphover-overlay fancybox',
    href: url || '#'
 }).css({
     textDecoration: 'none'
 }).attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
```